# Create multiple concurrent POST requests, with JSON body having distinct ID value in each request

Tags: java, rest, post, postman

I need to make around 100 POST request.

The body of every post request needs to have a different ID.

Sample BODY

```
   { 
        id: 1,
        name: "ABC",
        city: "NY"
   }
```

All 100 requests should have different 'id' , but rest of the data can be the same

Can I attain this through Postman ? ..or some other tool?

Tried:

Assigned value to a variable, and used that as value for ID in Postman, but unable to change this variable for every request

Comment: Somebody just downvoted the Question. Kindly put the reason in comments for same. Thanks !

Comment: You mentioned concurrent, do you want 100 at the same time?

Comment: @DannyDainton Yes. I plan to use Postman Runner. trying with your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `{{$randomInt}}` to the POST body, save that request and then open the Collection Runner.

In the iteration count, type 100 and start the run. That will create a random id value for each request between 1 - 1000. As this is "random" this is the potential for the same value to be sent more than once.

Alternatively, you could add a `{{id}}` variable to the POST request body. Then create a CSV file with a single column which has `id` as the header - add the ID values you want as 100 new rows in the column.

In the Collection Runner, select the created CSV file and run that with your request.

There are a number of different ways that this can be done, it's just finding the use case that suits your context.

Answer (score 0):

You can the pre-request scripts in postman to send multiple request.

You can use

```
postman.setNextRequest("request_name");
```

To keep sending request till some condition is reached

Comment: I believe.. your answer guides me to make multiple requests. This can be achieved by Postman Runner. My question is to how I get different values for an ID field in JSON request body.. in every request.. sequential values prefrred